# Unable to Merge Images Java using Loop

Tags: java

I am trying below code to merge images but final image has only last image in output.
Using for loop i am trying to add multiple images to a single image.
Please advise.

```
package imageMerge;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Merge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File folder = new File("images");
        Merge m=new Merge();
        m.processFiles(folder);
        


        
    }
    public void processFiles(final File folder) {
        String filename="";
        BufferedImage c=null;
        try {
            int i=1;
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isFile() && !fileEntry.getName().contains("final")) {
                filename=fileEntry.getName();
                c = new BufferedImage(5000, 5000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics g = c.getGraphics();
                System.out.println(filename);
                    BufferedImage a = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\images\\"+filename));
                    System.out.println(a.getHeight());
                    c.createGraphics().drawImage(a, 0, 0, null);
                    i+=1;
            }
        }
        ImageIO.write( c, "png", new File ( "D:\\images\\final.png" ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You always draw the image at the same position: 0, 0

Comment: You create a new `BufferedImage` in each iteration of the loop overwriting the previous one. You need to create it outside of the loop and add image to it in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks @NoeXWolf, I am trying to add image one by one vertically. Can you help me with code ?. I am not sure how to get correct x,y values for position for next item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there are several issues :

1. In your loop, you are overwriting the content of the final image at each iteration, the graphics object of the final image must be declared once, before the loop.
2. You are attempting to write each image at the same coordinates (0,0). If you want to arrange the images vertically, use a variable (`yPosition` here) to keep track of the current y location .
3. You don't have to create `new File`, `fileEntry` is already the `File` object you want

Putting it all together :

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Merge {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final File folder = new File("D:\\images");
        Merge m = new Merge();
        m.processFiles(folder);

    }

    public void processFiles(final File folder) {
        String filename = "";

        BufferedImage c = new BufferedImage(5000, 5000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = c.createGraphics(); // 1)

        int yPosition = 0; // 2)


        try {
            int i = 1;
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (fileEntry.isFile() && !fileEntry.getName().contains("final")) {
                    filename = fileEntry.getName();

                    System.out.println(filename);
                    BufferedImage a = ImageIO.read(fileEntry); // 3)
                    System.out.println(a.getHeight());
                    g.drawImage(a, 0, yPosition, null); // 2)


                    yPosition = yPosition + a.getHeight(); // 2)
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
            ImageIO.write(c, "png", new File("D:\\images\\final.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Code. It works but the images are not coming up one below the other . Instead it's coming on top of each other

Comment: Did you add `yPosition = yPosition + a.getHeight();`  ? Because this should fix the problem .

Comment: Thanks I was able to generate it. Now the problem is generated final image is appearing very small even though size is correct. Any fix for that ?

Comment: When running this code, the images in the final image all have kept their original size, maybe try opening the image with another software (e.g Paint) .